# Making a 2X5 table with CSS?

Tags: css

I basically need a table that has 2 columns and 5 rows where column one takes 30% of the nested div and column 2 takes the remaining 70%. I'm tempted to make a table but I do not think this is proper now day.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using the table to display data?

Comment: @nightfirecat Yes, for example, Name, Price, etc

Comment: Then it's absolutely proper - that's exactly what the tag is used for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply use the `<col />` tag (which is used for styling columns), and apply the CSS `width` property to it: [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/Y86HT/)

Answer (score 0):

Tables are entirely correct and proper for tabular data as you are wanting to do. That's what tables are in the spec for. Trying to make a table with CSS for this is entirely unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

It's proper to use a `<table>` if you're displaying data. Using it for layouts isn't proper, but using it for data would be more proper than creating a table with CSS.

Answer (score 0):

```
<table style="width:100%">
<tr>
<td style="width:30%">your text here</td>
<td>other text here</td>
</tr>
...
</table>
```

If you actually need 5x2 cells formatted like a table, making a div equivalent would certainly take longer.
I'm not entirely sure about the , though. But if it works, the second  should be 70% without overflow on the right because of the borders, margins, and padding.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a table of data, then the `<table>` tag is still the correct solution.

The concept of "tableless design" only applies to the practice of using tables to do the layout (eg a table column for the right hand menu bar and another for the main page body). This is bad practice, and should no longer be done; for this kind of layout, `<div>` elements and CSS are a better solution.

However if the content you wish to display is actually a table of data, then you should still be using the `<table>` tag.

In fact, the phrase "tableless design" is a bad phrase itself, as it causes exactly the confusion you're having.

A better way of saying it is "semantic design". Semantic means using elements and class names which make logical sense, so that if a search engine or other scanning program reads your page, it can understand what type of content it is seeing at by looking at the tags. Therefore a `<table>` element is good for tables of data because it is logical, but if a navigation menu is in a `<table>` it doesn't make sense.

Hope that helps.